# React embedding PDF using react-pdf not working

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to use [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) to render a pdf document. I have a react app generated by create-react-app. I have followed the instructions mentioned in the github readme for CRA (https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf#create-react-app).

```
import { Document, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

**I have placed a sample PDF file in `./public/dummy.pdf`.**

[image]

**And it is accessible at**
[image]

**I am using the Document component as below but nothing gets rendered on the page**.

```
<Document file="http://localhost:3000/dummy.pdf" />
```

[image]

**This is what it looks like in React DevTools for Chrome**
[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Document` component mostly deals with fetching the PDF and managing loading/error states. To render the pages of the PDF, you need to render `Page` component passing the corresponding page number.

Slightly modified version of the [example taken from Usage section](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf#usage) to render all pages of the PDF:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

function MyApp() {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Document
        file="dummy.pdf"
        onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
      >
        {[...Array(numPages).keys()].map((p) => (
          <Page pageNumber={p + 1} />
        ))}
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So we need to go through it page by page, or does all pages get rendered?

Comment: If you want to render all pages of the PDF, you need to render `Page` component for each page passing the page number as prop.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try! Thanks ☺️

Comment: Make sure to visit Recipes wiki, often overlooked part of React-PDF documentation, which handles most popular use cases: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/wiki/Recipes